# What Java library can map a PostgreSQL array literal to a Java array or list?

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql

What third-party Java class library is available to map a [PostgreSQL array literal](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/arrays.html) string to a Java array or list of strings?

For example, suppose I wish to convert a PostgreSQL array literal string such as

```
{ A, B, C }
```

into the equivalent Java `List<String>` or `Array<String>` that contains `{ "A", "B", "C" }`.  Does the the [PostgreSQL JDBC driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/) have a class method to perform this conversion?

Comment: Did you find any solution of it? I'm stuck with the same problem. My query returns an array literal which I need to parse!

Answer (score 5):

Why would you want to parse array string literals in Java, when you can just get a `java.sql.Array` from PgJDBC and call `getArray()` on it to get the native Java array directly?

Parsing array literals in Java seems like an unnecessarily complicated approach.

Since you're getting the values as array literals from `hstore`, I'd say that you have a bit of a data model design problem since hstore really only stores string values so storing array literals is a wee bit ugly. I can understand that there might be circumstances where it's desirable though, at least until Pg gets improved `json` support.

In that case I'd let PostgreSQL parse the array literals for you. Given setup:

```
regress=# CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
CREATE EXTENSION
regress=# CREATE TABLE hstoretest ( test hstore );
CREATE TABLE
regress=# INSERT INTO hstoretest(test) VALUES ( hstore( ARRAY['a', 'b'], ARRAY[ ARRAY[1,2,3]::text, ARRAY[9,8,7]::text ] ) );
INSERT 0 1
regress=# INSERT INTO hstoretest(test) VALUES ( hstore( ARRAY['a', 'b'], ARRAY[ ARRAY[11,12,13]::text, ARRAY[99,88,77]::text ] ) );
INSERT 0 1
regress=# SELECT * FROM hstoretest ;
                 test                 
--------------------------------------
 "a"=>"{1,2,3}", "b"=>"{9,8,7}"
 "a"=>"{11,12,13}", "b"=>"{99,88,77}"
(2 rows)
```

You could let Pg expand and parse the array literals for you with something like:

```
regress=# SELECT k, fetchval(test,k)::integer[] FROM (SELECT test, skeys(test) AS k FROM hstoretest) withkeys;
 k |  fetchval  
---+------------
 a | {11,12,13}
 b | {99,88,77}
 a | {1,2,3}
 b | {9,8,7}
(4 rows)
```

You may need more or less complicated variants depending on whether you're fetching just one hstore field or many fields, whether all your values are arrays of the same type or not, etc. In some cases you'll need to do individual SQL calls to unpack values.

Comment: You raise a good point.  I neglected to mention in my original question that the array literal is one of the values contained within an `hstore` column.  PgJDBC returns the hstore object as a `Map<String, String>` where in this case, the value is the array literal. Though this array is presently limited to one dimension, I'd ideally like to parse a multi-dimensional array.  I could write the parser, but as you point out, this could be complicated and unnecessary if PgJDBC already provides one.

Comment: A custom parser could also be fragile should a future version of PgJDBC change the array representation.

Comment: @DerekMahar Answer extended with suggested approach

Comment: This would certainly work, except we already have these arrays stored this way in an attribute table.  In order to avoid costly table joins for each attribute, I've been experimenting with `hstore` in order to see how query performance might be improved if we were to move all of the attributes for a particular entity into an `hstore` column in the same row as its entity.  Translating the array keys back into rows somewhat defeats this purpose.

Comment: @DerekMahar It doesn't defeat the purpose at all; you're still avoiding numerous joins and just doing a simple iteration over a result set. About the only other alternative I see is to submit a patch to PgJDBC that exposes its internal array parsing mechanism as a public utility API, or to add support for hstores with typed values to the driver. Neither will be particularly popular ideas so you may land up relying carrying private PgJDBC patches forward.

Comment: @DerekMahar Another option is to upgrade to 9.3 as soon as it comes out and use the enhanced `json` support.

Comment: Does or will the `json` type support query operators and functions similar to those that `hstore` provides?  Are `json` queries likely to be as performant as `hstore` queries?

Comment: @DerekMahar Yes and yes; the new `json` type started life as "hstore 2".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has. Take a look at: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/49107A7D.3050206@gmail.com. Also there is an interesting article [here](http://tech.valgog.com/2009/02/passing-arrays-to-postgresql-database.html). That article has a comment linking to an interesting project on GitHub (sproc-spring-mapper).

Comment: The PostgreSQL mailing list post describes how to save a Java array to a PostgreSQL array column.  I need to do the reverse: convert a PostgreSQL array literal string that you would see when querying an array column with psql.

Comment: I suggest you take a look to ActiveRecord then. It may get the results you want and will save you a LOT LOT of work.

Comment: @JosueMontano Er ... ActiveRecord? Java? Are you thinking of an ORM - a JPA implementation like Hibernate or EclipseLink, say?

Comment: @Josue Do you know of an ORM solution that can process an hstore column containing a set of literal string values of mixed types that  includes arrays?

Answer (score 0):

For whom needs to parse array value from logical replication(pgoutput):
In such situation, it's so good/familiar/high-performance to use the sql way in Craig Ringer's answer, so I wrote a [Class](https://gist.github.com/alex-lx/d67743fa1b676f5df8c19525b20fe1fd) to parse it.